# What happens if some polygons are empty in reduce() in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, ndvi, point-in-polygon, time-series

I am drawing the NDVI time-series trend for two types polygon in my target area using Sentinel-2. I don't know why I miss one day's NDVI mean. Is it because some polygons are unmasked after cloudrmove? The second picture describe the image in that day.(12.22.2017)
[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi Yin Liu, if it is possible, can you include the code you are using, or mock up an example to share. If there are no image pixels intersecting the geometry being reduced by, the returned reduction will be null and not plot on the chart. If, however, some parts of the geometry intersect valid pixels, you will get a valid reduction result that will plot. Here is a [demo](https://code.earthengine.google.com/a471fd22150a32dafc855285e5c53f30?as_external). We need to see your code to understand better what is happening.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation.

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/9d97c7b1fe7683c81c6a97e1444e61da

Comment: This is my code. And I have divide my polygon into two parts. The plot on the chart describe the two parts averagy NDVI for every points in every polygon. I have two questions. 1) If there is one polygon without masked image, will the function calculate the other polygons' average NDVI and display it on the graph? 2) How to ignore two specific date images and just diaplay other date images on the graph?